# How to transfer contacts from iPhone to PC?

Tags: iphone, contacts

I have contacts on my iPhone 5 that I wish to transfer to my PC. I know how to transfer photos from iPhone to PC, but I don't know how to do the same for contacts. How can I transfer contacts?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Stack Exchange is English-only; I've edited your question to English and feel free to edit further if I've edited out something relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of the free apps (e.g. [My Contacts Backup](https://itunes.apple.com/at/app/my-contacts-backup/id446784593?mt=8)) on the AppStore to export all of your contacts and Mail it to your e-Mail account or save it to Dropbox etc.

Another way is, if you have your Contacts on iCloud. SignIn on [icloud.com](http://www.icloud.com) navigate to Contacts - Press `cmd`+`A` or `ctrl`+`A` on Windows. The in the corner left ist a Gear Symbol - and select Export vCard